# Should I spend 3/4 of my savings to buy a new car that costs about a year of my annual salary?

Tags: savings, car

Since I still live with my parents I've been saving money for a while. All these savings amount to around 15 months of my current salary.

Now I need a car.

Cars are pretty expensive. I don't want to buy a used car and be stuck with mechanical problems to be fixed every now and then. That costs money.

So I decided to go for a new car.

The car I want to buy would cost 75% of my current savings.

Would you purchase a car in that manner?

The other option is monthly installments which would lower my monthly savings to pay for the car loan.

What do you think would be money wise here?

**Update**

- My wage is around £800 and cars costing £800 where I live are just plain garbage (wires are hanging out and all) A decent cheap (likeable or not) car starts around £3000.. Those are actual numbers; I just used internet currency converter
- It took 2 years to gather my savings
- I don't think I'll be living with my parents in 5 years (maybe in 1 or 1 and half years moving out will become an idea to think about)
- If I save money to the same rate till the end of this year, I will have enough savings to buy an economic house or enough down payment to buy for a midlevel standing apartment/house
- Since it was asked several times in the comments, let me say that:
  I'm from **Africa** (West Africa). I was hopping more for common sense and money wise like answers. I got a lot more valuable answers/comments than I expected. You guys are awesome. It'll take me a little more time than I thought to read all these. Feel free though to take into account this location in you answers/comments

Comment: "I don't wanna buy a used car and be stuck with mechanical problems to be fixed every now and then. That costs money..." yeah but it costs a lot less money than a new car that will _also_ have mechanical problems eventually...

Comment: Paying from your savings is a very good idea. Paying this *much* of your savings on a car is very much *not* a good idea.

Comment: @chepner How much would be reasonnable ? In your view ? Would you say 25% of much much less

Comment: I saved and paid cash for a new car that was ~28% of my annual salary at the time. (Many would say I still overpaid.) In the 9 years since, though, I haven't come close to paying an additional 50% in maintenance and repairs. Keep in mind, also, how long you will continue to be able to save money at your current rate, i.e., how long will you be able to have your parents cover a large chunk of your living expenses.

Comment: Also, take a moment to think about how 2026-steve will feel about you spending that much money on a car today. You may think you have nothing better to do with the money, but he will probably think otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26324/should-i-buy-my-first-car-with-all-of-my-savings

Comment: @yoozer8 Yeah it helps. Mine wasn't about using 100% but 75 % of savings made from full time job salary. I'm already graduated from school... But yeah, that question helps Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why do you show up to a job interview in nice clothes? What image is projected by a lawyer in a broken-down old car? Why is dating any different? In fact, why do you dress up to go on a date?

Comment: "I don't want a used car" Why not buy a used car from a dealership with the benefits of a new car at less of a price? I've always (since my first new car) bought "New Used" - cars from the dealership, right off of lease and with all the insurance and warranties of a "new car". BRAND new car loses thousands in price when it drives off the lot... you can buy a leased 3 year old car for that thousands less and have all the benefits... Also, how much are you going to be driving? Lots? Little?

Comment: These days new cars are more like financial instruments that converts people's lives into ETFs.

Comment: It takes tens of tonnes of CO2 to manufacture a new car - can your carbon budget take that hit? If you want those embedded emissions to "count" more it's best to keep second-hand cars going for longer.

Comment: You need to let us know the country, or you're going to get a lot of useless answers, since the situation for cars is extremely country(continent)-specific

Comment: Compare the following strategies: (A) buy a new car for say $20,000 and drive it till either you get bored with it, or it costs a lot of money to repair. (B) buy a used car for say $2,000, and if it needs more than say $200 to repair it, scrap it and buy another one for $2000. Repeat 10 times. Which strategy do you think will cost you more, over say 10 years?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I buy my first car with all of my savings?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26324/should-i-buy-my-first-car-with-all-of-my-savings)

Comment: "I don't wanna buy a used car and be stuck with mechanical problems to be fixed every now and then." A new car loses 15-20% of its value the second you drive it off the lot.  Buy a one-year old used car and you will have all the benefits you seek with *significant* savings on the initial purchase.

Comment: @Zibbobz One year old cars are huge red flags. That's why they're cheap. People don't normally keep cars for one year. Leases are 3-4. While somebody simply may not have liked a car, such a car is likely to have been abused (rental, repo) or is a lemon. The latter is very concerning since manufacturers have learned to preemptively buy back a car to avoid title branding.

Comment: Don't buy a new car, buy a 5-year old. Mechanically almost new, for much less than the full price.

Comment: @WernerCD hit it on the head.  2-3 year old cars hit a sweet spot of "almost indistinguishable from new" while also costing about 50% what their new counterparts cost.  They rarely have any more problems than a new car, they often look and feel just like a new car, and you save a lot of money.  This method also avoids having to deal with the major inconvenience of having things break and taking time off to fix them, which many proponents of 'buy a 15 year old car' often gloss over.

Comment: Buying a new car is generally an act of stupidity for most people.

Comment: Another huge advantage to buying used is that you can research repair rates by model year, and pick a model year that is known to have less mechanical issues. When you buy a new car, you'll be the one doing this research for the rest of us who buy used :)

Comment: "The other option is monthly installments which would lower my monthly savings to pay for the car loan." But spending all of a sudden, 75% of your savings is much worse. People always want to maintain their liquidities. It's not a good idea to just have 25% of your savings after that.

Comment: @aminabzz I see what you mean

Comment: Your percentages are causing more harm than good because they leave too much for us to guess. If you had £1 million then I would certainly not tell you to buy a £750k personal vehicle. If you have £5,000 then £3,750 is a reasonable figure. If you earn £2k/month then a £300/month financed vehicle, assuming low APR, isn't a bad choice either. If you're trying to buy a Mercedes then you'll probably end up paying thousands upon thousands during the first 5-10 years of ownership; people end up selling their luxury vehicles because the repair cost is astronomical.

Comment: You're doing yourself a disservice by implying you're in the UK (using £ in the example) rather than stating/tagging your actual locale, as people are answering based on UK conditions, which may well be completely off-base for your geo-political situation.

Comment: In the UK, £3000 is still used car terrority. The cheapest new car on sale today is £7,995 (Dacia Sandero).

Comment: As I've commented on several SE sites - the location of OP is very relevant to the question. Here, importantly so. Telling us is going to help. Not telling us - forget it.

Comment: @Tim I'm from Africa (west africa to be more recise). I don't know if it's going to help. I was hopping more for common sense and money wise like answers. And I got more than expected (it's going to take me more time than I thought to read all these answers and comments... you guys are awesome). Feel free to take this location into your answer/comment

Comment: @JasonKrs - thanks for that. In different parts of the world, vehicles' values differ. Which can make a big difference, in turn, to any answers. And finances can also vary considerably between countries. Your currency may be buoyant, may be dropping daily in value. These factors  (and other geographical ones) will be relevant. You certainly have your moneys worth here!

Answer (score 120):

If your current savings represents 15 months of salary and the car you are looking at purchasing costs 75% of your current savings, that means that buying a car that costs 11.25 months of your current salary.  That is an *insanely* expensive car relative to your means.  From a financial perspective, buying this car would be devastating.  I would strongly suspect that you are discounting the cost of maintaining this new car and that you are inflating the cost of dealing with occasional mechanical problems with a decent used car that you can more comfortably afford.

Money wise, the best course of action would be to reconsider the plan.  Buy a much (much) less expensive used car that you can much more comfortably afford.  Deal with the occasional mechanical issue that will inevitably appear.  Drive that car until the wheels fall off.

Comment: Drive it longer: wheels can be replaced :)

Comment: I see.... The cheapest used car I liked and saw on internet is about 3.5 month of current salary which mean I'd take up to 16% of my current saving. Would that be a good deal or should I go even lower ?  How much lower

Comment: @chepner lol that's funny and so true

Comment: @steve without knowing where you are in the world or what your salary actually is, that seems unlikely. Around here even at minimum wage with a full time job you'd be bringing home approx £1200 / month post-tax. A cheap used car can be had for less than half of that. Now I'm not saying this means it's sensible to buy the absolute cheapest car you can find, but it seems like you might be adding some extra constraints on your searching?

Comment: Ah, since I wrote my comment you've edited yours to include cars you *liked*. Only you can decide how much the monetary value is to you of getting a car you like, versus one that will get you from A to B as needed.

Comment: "Drive that car until the wheels fall off."  Plan B: Tight the lug nuts!   :->)

Comment: @Vicky Hahaha... Now I know why people flee to europe. My wage is around £ 800 and cars costing £ 800 where I live are just plain garbage (wires are hanging out and all) A decent cheap (likeable or not) car starts around £ 3000.... Those are actual numbers I just used internet currency converter

Comment: @steve You barely seem to make minimum wage. Now is not the time to be spending all your money on a single car. Are you still in school (high school or college), have you considered insurance and routine maintenance costs, do you have a plan for *not* living with your parents in 5 years, etc?

Comment: @chepner Believe it or not. That a pretty decent wage from where I'm from. Minimum wage from where I'm from is £ 80. Actually, I graduated 2 years ago. Been saving since then. And yes, I hope I'll be able to leave in my own house...

Comment: @chepner: Actually happened to me once.  Took it in for new tires, and the shop forgot to put the lug nuts on one of the wheels.

Comment: I love the utterly US/UK centric answers to this question. Oh you should get a car for 600 pounds. That is utterly impossible even for example in the Czech republic. Absolute minimum is about 1600 pounds and that's a car that will break down in months if not weeks. Not everywhere is the US/UK. And 1600 pounds is roughly 1.5x the MEDIAN monthly salary.

Comment: yeah, even in Germany, cars are expensive! Way more than in the UK. The standard and costs to pass the bi-annual vehicle inspection (HU or TÜV) is also much higher. My 10 yr old car cost me 3000 EUR. There was an expensive steering issue fixed under warranty. I then had to do the cambelt and then the multi/HT thingy). 200 in parts. Labour would have been as much again but I can do it happily.

Comment: Then the clear answer is... **don't** get the darned car. You have the luck to live in Europe with all this usable public transportation. Most of the time "I need a car" means "I haven't thought hard enough how to not need the car". Paying an entire year's salary to save a little bit of thinking...

Comment: @obscurans Another sweeping generalization. Not everybody lives in London, Paris or Berlin. People live outside urban areas, and based on the OP saying minimum wage is £80, he is most certainly not in the wealthy West, but in non-EU Eastern Europe. Ignoring that, people who must work late nights will also find public transit problematic, even in major cities.

Comment: @obscurans since he's talking about people fleeing to Europe, I think he's somewhere in Africa/middle east or somewhere in the "stans" (Kazakhstan, Turkmenistan, Afghanistan,....)

Comment: @mishan: Or, given the wage in £, they're British. British people often refer to Europe (as in mainland Europe) as a separate place.

Comment: @ShadowRanger since he mentioned in the comments that minimum wage is around 80 pounds where he is from and the cars costing 800 pounds are the absolute clunkers that are not road worthy I think it unlikely. And that he converts the prices to pounds in currency converter online.

Comment: @DRF Perhaps there's another Czechia somewhere, but in the one I know, you can certainly find loads and loads of used cars for less than €/$/£ 1000. We're talking about ~15 years old small cars with 100-150k km on them, and those will still happily serve you for at least five years.

Comment: @TooTea They’re likely cheap because they have obsolete emissions which poses an issue if you’re driving in urban areas. Most large German and French cities ban pre-Euro 4 (2005 and earlier). London has a charge for anything older than Euro 4 gas and Euro 6 diesel. Albania banned the import of pre-Euro 5 vehicles.

Comment: "From a financial perspective, buying this car would be devastating" In what sense? He lives with his parents and probably has no other expenses?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sure, that's an important factor. But you rarely _need_ a car to move around said city centers, so there's still a lot of valid uses for these aging cars. It's clear that cars at this price point come with a lot of compromises to be made compared to cars at 10-20x the price.

Comment: @GlenRunciter - The car costs 11.25 months worth of salary.  The cost of maintenance, insurance, taxes, etc. will add to that and will become expenses that he has to continue to pay.  He lives with his parents now but, presumably, doesn't want to do so forever.  Savings spent on a car are savings that can't go toward getting an apartment, making a down payment on a house, etc.

Comment: @Justin Cave And there is no maintenance/insurance with used cars? Actually quite a bit more of those two things....

Comment: @GlenRunciter - Insurance on a new car will almost certainly be more expensive than insurance on a used car.   Yes, there will be maintenance costs for a used car but those costs will likely be dwarfed by the price difference between the cars.  And, like I said, my wager is that the original poster is underestimating the maintenance costs of a new car and overestimating the maintenance costs of a new car.

Comment: @GlenRunciter From a US-centric POV, insurance on a used car is less, because you don't typically don't purchase collision or comprehensive insurance on a used car more than a few years old. Maintenance on my 15-year-old Toyota is minimal.

Comment: @shoover Run the insurance numbers. Comprehensive and collision on your Toyota is going to be around $40 a year. I was going to cancel it on a 15 year old car and the numbers were so small versus liability, it didn't make a difference. They figure you're not going to make claims either when your bumper gets scratched. Similarly, I replaced the old car, effectively worthless, with a brand new one, and my insurance went up by 15%. Modern features like anti-collision braking, stability control, and backup cameras have a real impact on loss rates.

Comment: @user71659 Actually for some reason I still have c&c on my 15yo Toyota. I live in a high-theft city, so my c&c premium is ~$125/year.

Comment: @TooTea: I think you may have mistagged; that comment didn't relate to anything I said.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh, indeed, I'm terribly sorry. No idea how that happened.

Comment: @tootea Hmm Where did you find them I can't find anything under 40k CZK and the ones at that cost point seem to be just at the edge of being able to pass inspection. Certainly not seeing anything in the 17k CZK range you would need to hit 600 pound equivalent. Maybe being in Prague is skewing my perceptions.

Comment: @user71659 it's called a bike, which functions most places (including those without good road systems). If you're in a place where ALL of (1) distances to be travelled are large (>20km) (2) public transportation doesn't work (3) bikes are sufficiently unsafe relative to a clunker (4) a car in these surroundings *doesn't* mark you immediately as rich enough to rob,  are **simultaneously** true, then you may start thinking of a car as "necessary".

Comment: @obscurans "If you're in a place where ... are simultaneously true, then" you may be in Houston, Texas.

Comment: @DRF You’re talking about 1.5x your monthly salary but the question is about 11.5x monthly salary. Seems like not a reasonable comparison. In the US, I think a car that is about 3x monthly salary can be reasonable. Almost a years’ salary is not.

Comment: @kpollock In my part of the US, $5000 for a 10 year old car can be reasonable. And that is around 2 months of the median income. 11.5x the median monthly income would be a pretty nice vehicle - foolishly extravagant for anyone actually earning the median or less.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I was reacting to the general idea that it is utterly ridiculous. The differences in car costs between the US and my country are insane. A new BMW in the US market will cost maybe half what it does in Czechia. (It's a little hard to directly compare since the models sold in different countries vary slightly) it gets much worse for used cars which seem to be harder to buy cheaply here. At the same time the median income is much lower in Czechia than in the US. So off the bat comparable cars will cost 4x as much of your median income.

Comment: @obscurans In COVID times not everyone wants to use public transport for safety reasons.

Comment: @DRF A used ten year old Toyota Camry or Ford Taurus  (their basic sedans in the US) in the mid Atlantic region of the US will cost about 4-5x the monthly median income. So I’m trying to say maybe things aren’t as different in the US as you seem to think. It’s still ridiculous in the US to spend more than twice that on a car if you’re only making the median income. I make 3x the median income and wouldn’t spend more than 2-4 months of it on a car.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Since it's getting long and I would be interested to talk some more let us take this discussion to chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124231/car-costs-around-the-world

Answer (score 58):

I just bought my daughter a car. A 2018 just coming off lease. 21,000 miles, and about half the price of the same car new. The money saved on insurance alone is significant. Her prior car was driven to 200,000 miles, and only the last 30,000 or so was heavy on repairs. In hindsight, we should have made the move at 150,000 or so. So her new car has about 80% of its life remaining and even some residual value after that.

Comment: Exactly this. You can pick up even a barely used car with a few hundred or few thousand miles on it for significantly cheaper than a new one. Speak to the dealer you want to purchase the new car from and they will gladly hook you up with a used one instead.

Comment: I bought a 4 yr old car with 95k for $7k, after 6 years I hit an expensive repair, and started looking to replace it, had 225k miles on it when I got rid of it.  Went with another 3 year old 100k car for $9k, it's been 3 years and 50k miles, no issues at all.    On the other hand I bought one that was a year old, 20k miles, and it had so many issues, I can only imagine how I would feel if I paid full price for that piece of junk.  Had another bought new that the horn would start honking randomly for no reason even when parked in the garage, no one could fix it...got rid of it after 3 years.

Comment: I wish I was your daughter for this specific situation. You'd get me a good deal I bet. From where I live, 21000 miles (33000 Km) is considered a one year used car. Maybe 5% to 10% max less expensive than original cars....

Comment: @JasonKrs: That's because you're looking at the _average_. Some people drive a lot, others drive very little. I used to have a car to go to work that I drove for only 30km per day (over hilly terrain, too lazy to bike). When I sold it after 3 years, I hadn't reached 10K km yet. Those are _rare_ cases, so they require research. How much time does it take you to earn 1K pounds? That's how much time you should be willing to invest in looking for saving up 1K pounds!

Comment: @MatthieuM. I see. I made a little computation. I'd need around £8000 to get a decent used car from the brand dealer from where I'm from. TO save that much money at my current savings rate, it would take me 21 month (HAHAHAH).... I think I need to move to UK/US to have a decent car with my wage .... But I get your point. I should compute is the savings time suits me and go for it instead of burning all my current savings

Comment: It can vary by location, I have a 5yo car with 110,000km (70,000mi) and they cost more in this state than they were new. Still better than getting scalped.

Answer (score 30):

**Always pay cash**. If you cannot afford a new car right away, buy a used one. If you cannot afford a used car, you are in no position to afford a car loan.

Whether 75% of your savings is too much, is depending on your **cash flow**. I am sure my first car (during university times) cost me more than 75% of savings. And after I started working, I got another car which again took most of my savings. But in both cases I had a good positive cash flow that was making up for this within less than a year.

Comment: This. Measure the savings not as a percentage of the total savings amount, but in terms of the length of time it's taken to get there. An amount which took nine months to accumulate is far more affordable than an amount which took nine years to accumulate. (Be sure to factor in running costs on the car you get: that will eat into the amount you used to save.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach It took me 2 years to reach my current savings. Almost Half of my wage is going into the savings... So I understand this is a big NO GO then. Because maintenance expense may prevent getting back those 75% back in 2 years.... Plus I may not still live with my parents in 2 years

Comment: @Jason I'm in the UK and it's illegal for me to give personal financial advice. But if my comment, this answer and the similar top-voted answer give pause for thought, that's probably valuable.

Comment: Does the rule "pay cash" still stand if lease is 0% loan - assuming you have cash to pay it all without getting any extra fees...

Comment: Yes. The main reason for paying cash is not to avoid interest payments. It is to avoid overextending yourself financially by only spending money you actually have. 0% financing is popular because it gives the buyer the impression of getting something cheap and for a low monthl rate. People are much less inclined to pay 30k instead of 20k for a car than they are to pay 200/month more. The latter simply does not look that costly

Comment: @Manziel Thank you for putting a word on my thought : " overextending ".  This is exactly what I don't want to do. I don't want to be in a situation in which I owe money to a bank for any amount of time. To me it's almost like living beyond my means.  Since I can't predict future cash flow (for instance I could just loose my job), I want to pay cash. For a house, it may be a different thinking

Answer (score 11):

It all depends on the interest rate being offered. You cannot make a generalization.

New car loans from the manufacturer are subvented. This is a major benefit to buying new. This means the manufacturer pays part of the financing cost out of its margins, in order to encourage sales of new cars.

I recently got a new car loan at "0%" APR. In reality, it was 0.9% because there's a cash rebate that I didn't receive.

I could have taken that money and deposited in a CD at the same company's finance arm and received 1.5% interest. That is, I could have been paid 0.6% to loan money to myself.

Obviously, I took the deal and kept the money in my existing investments, which easily realize 10x that, and I still have access to that money if an emergency occurs.

Additionally, for younger people, an installment loan on your credit record will greatly help you get a mortgage. (Credit scores for mortgages distinguish between long-term installment loans versus revolving credit cards)

The actual interest rate being offered depends on your creditworthiness and country. You need to determine what interest rate is being offered, and how that compares to alternatives including the benefits of having more rainy-day funds.

Comment: Given that a car loses at the very least 10% (a very conservative estimate, usually much more) in the first few months of owning it, that cheap credit turned out rather more expensive when compared to buying a used one year old car.

Comment: @Voo Myth. I actually looked at Black Book values deciding on whether I needed gap insurance and found depreciation followed payments closely. Besides it’s irrelevant. I value my time more than the hassle of other peoples car problems, I have assets that are at risk in an accident to others, and I place a monetary value on my life that I am motivated to get the latest safety features.

Comment: I bought a one year old skoda Octavia (aka the most popular car in Germany/Austria currently) last year from a dealer and the new one with the same equipment would've cost about 25% more (including the cash rebates and the usual tricks). I doubt you'll find any evidence that a one year old car is statistically more dangerous than a new one (if anything you find repairs/problems in the first few months are much higher than after that). Also if that were so important you'd have to replace your new car every year which I doubt you do either.

Comment: (But if you can show me some actual examples of people selling a year old car for virtually the same price as new, I'd be very impressed.. also very interested because that seems like a great deal for me. Might depend on the country, but it's certainly not the case in the US or Austria).

Comment: @Voo A one year old car is a huge red flag. Leases are 3-4 years. Nobody switches cars annually as you say. A 1 year old car was subject to abuse (rental or repo) or was repurchased due to repeated faults (so called lemon law in the US). I never said it was the same price. I said it depreciated in line with the payments. What you also have to consider is that the price of a car sold to a dealer is lower than what you buy it at. The dealer obviously has to cover costs and make a profit, which are at minimum $1000-1500 per car, which causes the spread.

Comment: Thanks to the whole covid situation, that analysis - at least over here - simply doesn't work. There's a lot of car fleet cars that have no use anymore, respectively dealer surplus what with dealerships being closed for months and people not buying cars. And apart from that special case there are demonstration cars, which can be great deals in general.

Comment: @Voo All of those examples fit under rental cars subject to abuse. In the US, fleet vehicles are permanently title branded for this reason and exactly suffer a loss in value. Demonstrators are a great example of abuse where the salespeople drive it hard to show off power and they're loaned to potential customers.

Comment: I guess those dealers trying to show off the power of a family car certainly hurts the car ;-) Although I do have to wonder if there's any actual statistics for that or if that's just a gut feeling. That fleet vehicles with high mileage are a problem is obvious and lowers the price appropriately.

Comment: @user71659 It's also worth noting repo can be a great deal.  I bought a 3 year old Camaro with 5k miles that was repoed and it was literally like new for about 45% the cost of new.  Repoed cars are not always abused or damaged.

Comment: Never get a loan for a personal vehicle. Cars depreciate. They depreciate faster than the paydown rate of the loan. Suggestion: 10% of your salary is an affordable amount for a car. That still leaves money for fuel, insurance, fees, repairs, etc. $0.02

Comment: Depreciation is irrelevant to the question of getting a loan, so I believe user71659 is correct, with this answer. Assuming the price of the car is the same either way, and you are determined to buy it, then the choice is between paying up front and paying slightly more over time. There's absolutely no reason to pay $100 now if you could invest it for 5 years, grow it to $160, and pay $101 out of that (oversimplifying a bit). The only time it wouldn't pay off is during a major, market downturn.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pay cash from savings to buy a car. 75% of your savings is probably fine, depending on your total savings and income level. This does not scale linearly, so concrete numbers would be helpful in better answering your question.

All cars have mechanical problems. Used cars probably have fewer than you think. New cars are a high price to pay to avoid them.

Comment: "75% of your savings is probably fine" the problem I have with that statement is the fact that if something goes wrong, can you afford a year of salary (roughly what he's made since it's 75% of 15 months of savings) for a replacement car? Seems a bit steep to pay THAT much for a car.

Comment: If you buy your used car from a reputable dealer it will come with a guarantee.

Comment: @RedSonja That's true. But from where I'm from, such cars only cost 5 to 15 % less than the original car. Might as well save a little more to simple buy a new car. I wish I lived in US/UK for this specific situation and get a decent car

Answer (score 2):

With few exceptions, if you borrow money, you will pay interest.  That means you are paying extra for that money.  This interest makes whatever you buy significantly more expensive.

There are only 2 advantages to taking out a loan and not using the money you already have:

1. You will have more money available for emergencies and the unexpected (and life rarely goes as planned).
2. You will have the opportunity to invest the money.  The only guaranteed investments earn almost zero interest right now, and all other investments carry significant risk of losing your principle.

Overall, I would recommend *against* taking out a loan.

Regarding the price of the vehicle, it would be ideal to spend less on the vehicle and save some of your money for emergencies, the unexpected, and charity.  But, if you have no other significant expenses, and don't foresee any in the near future, spending 75% of your savings may be okay.  Don't forget about taxes, maintenance, disposables (tyres aren't cheap!), insurance, and petrol.  Plus, if you keep your job, you will have a steady source of income.

That said, buying a new vehicle is almost always a rip-off.  As soon as you take it off the lot, most vehicles depreciate by 15-20%.  That's money you just lost and can't get back.

Your best value will likely be to buy a vehicle a few years old that has already experienced that instant depreciation.  With the money you save, you'll be able to afford a whole lot of maintenance, which may or may not be needed.

Is it a bit of a gamble?  Yes.  That's the downside.  But if you pay an independent mechanic to inspect a used vehicle before purchase, you'll hopefully have a reasonable idea of its condition.  Of course, the mechanic likely won't be looking inside the engine valves, so they won't be able to see everything.

Don't forget, new vehicles can often be a big headache too.  For example, according to Toyota, the Toyota Prius is allowed to consume up to 1L of oil every 1000km (that's 1.1qt per 600 miles) before Toyota will even start to consider it a problem.  The car dealership isn't going to tell you that sort of thing before you hand over your money.

Answer (score 2):

As the new vs. old question is addressed well in other answers, I'd like to address the question of loan vs. cash.

Although taking out a loan costs additional money over the long run, there is a key advantage of a loan that has not been mentioned in other answers:

**Regular payments on a car loan will build positive credit history.** It sounds like you're pretty young, so this could have a significant impact when you're looking to make other big moves in your life like renting an apartment (landlords check credit history) or buy a house (better interest rate).

Comment: This answer appears to be quite US/UK-centric.  In Germany and many other continental European countries, having had a car loan will have exactly zero impact on renting an apartment.

Comment: Never pay interest in order to save interest. There are free ways to build a credit history, if you are careful with your spending (put purchases on a credit card, even a prepaid card if necessary, and pay it off every month).

Comment: I would argue that there's a significant time-management and attention-cost benefit to fixed payments  that one can "set and forget."

Comment: @gerrit even in the UK, credit score does not affect renting, only getting a mortgage

Comment: @fqq My letting agent in England in 2015 asked me for a credit record from the previous years, including my years in Canada.  I don't know if they used that information, though.

Comment: In Belgium, I don't think something like "credit score" exists.

Comment: [Czech Republic, to contribute to the EU narrative] While financial organizations may track your financial history, more or less legally, I don't think the concept "credit score" is nearly as present anywhere else in the world as it is in the US. It likely has a lot to do with the normalization of a life spent in debt (at least subjectively, as perceived through popular media), hence the encouragement of a loan by this answer. The fact that you needed a loan in the past should never be a positive indication to any financial institution. Having a stable income is a much bigger key factor here.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon US-centric: The problem with that logic is that FICO distinguishes between revolving credit cards and installment loans (also prepaid cards have no impact... particularly since no SSN is given). A credit card lets you defer large chunks of payments, and you can adjust your spending if you lose your job, an installment loan does not. Without an installment loan, such as a car or student loan, on your record, you can find your FICO mortgage score to be a step lower than your general score. A subtended (subsidized interest) car loan is a cheap way to get installment experience.

Answer (score 2):

**Buying used cars is more expensive in the long run, and you have the money to buy a new/barely used car**

Edit (clarifying for the comment below): I'm all for buying cars with up to 10/15k miles already on them (and still has some factory warranty) that are a cheaper than a full priced new car, what I'm against is what the top answer is suggesting "Buy a MUCH (MUCH) cheaper used car and just deal with the mechanical issues"

Used cars are a crapshoot, and are never actually as cheap as people claim (some folks will tell you "Yea just pick up a used gem of a car for like $1,000 and drive it until it falls apart", terrible advice for many reasons). If you want to try your luck buying $3,000 used cars every couple of years like people here are suggesting it, go for it.

New cars have factory warranties so you're guaranteed to not have any problems (or at least not pay for ones you might have) and beyond the factory warranty if you drive it properly (dare I say gingerly), maintain it properly (oil changes, etc), and keep an eye out for any potential leaks/puddles under the chassis, it'll last a VERY long time.

It's similar to home buying vs. renting: If you don't have money for a down payment on a house, the obvious short term cheaper option is to rent, same as with cars: if you don't have cash for a new or slightly  used car: buy cheap cars and pray like hell, but OP *does* have the cash. It's like OP is asking "I have $200k in savings, should I buy a house for $150k?" and people are telling him "No, that's too much of your savings, you should rent instead"

My opinion: use 50% of your savings on the car, borrow the rest, drive the car properly and keep up with maintenance. Barring the incredibly rare, new car automotive horror story, you'll have the car for a very long time. OR, since you're not really at risk of being homeless should you lose your job or hit financial hardship, buy the car outright using 75% of your savings... especially if you're planning on sticking around your parents place for a little longer, live frugally and save back up to where you're at now.

**this is going to get downvoted because everyone here is answering from their own perspective: most likely they're adults, they have a home, possibly children, and other financial concerns, so to them, dropping "75% of their savings on a car" is a DRASTICALLY different thing than your own situation, but they don't see it, OP: get the car, treat it properly, you won't have to worry about cars for 20+ years, if you start playing musical chairs with used cars every couple years you'll wish you hadn't. If "buying a used car and driving it until the wheels fall off, or until you get sick of it breaking down" is the best idea, why does almost no one who is gainfully employed, with positive cash flow and savings do it (not to mention with more than enough savings to buy a new one outright)? I'd bet the authors of answers telling you to go the "purchase a used car and drive it until it dies" route are NOT doing that themselves, and have a car they purchased new, or they lease**

Comment: There's a huge difference between buying a $1000 hooptie and fixing it all the time (not necessarily a negative) vs buying a solid used car for 25% to 50% less than a new vehicle.

Comment: Almost all of my cars have been used, usually about 3 years old. I could have easily afforded new cars, but this plan is one of the reasons that I was able to retire at 60.

Comment: See the edit I made, I'm all for that, what I'm against is what the top answer is suggesting, used cars that are, in their words "MUCH (MUCH)" less, and just putting up with the inevitable mechanical issues, that's ridiculous. At that point they're talking about 2nd hand super cheap crappy cars from strangers, not resellers who buy GOOD cars from rental fleets that are only 1-2 model years older, still have factory warranty, and only have like 10k miles on them, those are great, but that's not the direction the answers are steering OP

Comment: I feel there is a flaw in logic here. Using your example, suppose a car has an average of a 20 year life expectancy. Then a 3-4 year old car has an average of a 16-17 year life expectancy. Since a 3-4 year old car is approximately half the cost of a new car, you absolutely would save money by buying a 3 year old car and keeping it for 17 years, vs paying double for a new car.

Comment: In the sense that, when considering housing, if you don't have cash/savings for a down payment on a house, the short term cheaper option is to rent, same as if you don't have savings for a new or slightly used car, you do what the top answer says: buy super cheap cars and pray like hell, but OP DOES have the liquidity... put the housing comparison this way: OP is asking "Guys I have $200k, should I buy a $150k house?" And people are saying "No that's too much of your savings, you should rent". Not to mention OP (seemingly, unless they didn't include it) has no other expenses...

Comment: "Buying used cars is more expensive in the long run" no, obv.

Comment: "you won't have to worry about cars for 20+ years" not true, obv.

Comment: @njzk2 What about the fact that the owner of the used car may not tell you what's wrong with its engine. He could be sneaky and just make a temporary fixes so that you have no idea something is wrong by make a mechanic technician check the car before buying it

Comment: I'm in my 50s with a net worth in the PAW range, and have not been without a car for 36 years. In that time I have owned exactly three vehicles, all purchased used, the latter two for cash. Not wasting several hundred dollars a month on car payments is part of why I've been able to save so much.

Comment: @GlenRunciter Car != House. Cars (vintage classics excepted) almost always depreciate over time. Houses sometimes lose value, but in the long run, almost always appreciate over time.

Comment: @JasonKrs That's why you have your mechanic check out the car before you purchase it. Any reasonable and reliable seller will allow this. If they don't, find another seller.

Comment: You're flat wrong. I track my costs very carefully.  My *sum total* acquisition and maintenance costs over the last 20 years **have been less than $100/month**. **Really.**  I put a ton of miles, that's the point, my cars are optimized for max miles for minimum $ (TCO). I can fix everything on it except short-block or trans, and it's a stickshift (not an automatic that fails randomly and is unrepairable).  So I don't get repair surprises.

Comment: @JasonKrs you can buy your used car from a dealership or a mechanic, with a warrantee on hidden defects. And of course, don't just buy the first piece of trash you find, do your research.

Comment: @JasonKrs for example, some car makers are reputed to be more reliable, have less expensive and more widely available spare parts. Some expensive repairs or maintenance are known to happen after some mileage, so aim under that (or see that the repairs have been made). Age is also a factor. All of that is a bit more complicated than buying new, but well worth it. Also note that a new car will loose value (both in relative and absolute terms) much faster than a used one.

Comment: Thinking that buying a new vehicle means it won't need work for a while is misleading. It's not unheard of for brand new vehicles to need repairs (possibly expensive) within the first couple years of ownership. Even if the work is covered under warranty, you still have the time it takes to repair the vehicle to deal with. Hopefully a loaner vehicle can be provided in that instance.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't finance and pay interest if you don't have to.

In your position, something to consider, is a 2-4 year old car with an *extended warranty*. In general, I don't think extended warranties are worth it, but one scenario where I think they are worth it may apply to you:

> If you are not considering purchasing a used car *primarily* because you don't want to deal with repair costs, and if an extended warranty enables you to consider it, then it may be cost effective to get the warranty, *compared to purchasing new*.

Note that you can be completely against extended warranties and it might still be rational to purchase one! The reason is to compensate for other irrational decisions which are more costly. This is not necessarily a bad thing either; car buying often entails irrational decisions. Home buying even more so! (I bought the specific car I bought because I wanted a manual transmission, and they are slim pickings these days.)

I have first hand experience purchasing an extended car warranty despite knowing it was probably irrational to do so. In 2019 my wife wanted to purchase a brand new vehicle that was $42K. She was burned in the past with many thousands of dollars of repairs on a vehicle, so I was able to convince her that we could buy a similar fully loaded 2016 model for $20K, but she wanted the extended warranty, so we added it for about $2K. Despite a potentially wasted $2K, from my point of view, we still saved $20K. (**Caveat**: if we change vehicles when the warranty ends the equity difference will be about $9K, meaning the true savings is closer to only $11K instead of $20K. Essentially we paid $2K to save $11K.) Within 6 months of purchase there was an issue that cost $1100 to fix, and our cost with the warranty was $100, so at this point the cost of the warranty was only $1000, though all that does is make me feel less worse about buying it. (As of now we paid $1K to save $11K.)

Comment: I think an extended warranty is worth it to avoid the nightmare scenario: you owe money on a car that's out of warranty.  In that case, a major breakdown happens, and the collateral is now worthless. The choice is a) pay the major repair, or b) the lender calls the note and pay that. Realistically the borrower can't do either one, so repo, credit burn, no car, can't keep job, death spiral.  The extended warranty saves you from that case, if it's any good.

Answer (score 1):

Spending the bulk of your savings on a £3000 car is a bad idea.  You'll need to have a lot of money back for repairs, because repairs are very expensive when you pay others to do them.

### At that funding level, the only sustainable option is DIY car maintenance.

You are simply being unrealistic to think you can take an older car and dole money out-of-pocket for every car repair that comes up.  What will more realistically happen is you will neglect the maintenance until a repair comes up that you simply cannot afford, and then you'll have to park it or give it up.  Even if you borrow and strain to pay that repair bill, around the corner will be *another one* that will finish you off.

However, the tables turn if you cultivate the skills (and tools) to maintain the car yourself.  Suddenly instead of a £400 brake job, you are spending £60 on the parts and £40 on tools (which you can keep and not have to buy a second time).

You put yourself at fullest advantage by buying a car that is a) popular, and b) dog simple.  Make those your priorities instead of "style" or "features".

And the first priority *there* is to get a traditional stick-and-clutch manual transmission. Why?  Unlike automatics, the transmission almost never fails (meaning, if yours *does* fail, you can easily get a used one off a wreck for £100).  Usually the clutch fails, and a clutch change is well within the reach of an amateur.

Likewise, manual steering removes two high-maintenance items: the steering gear, and the belt driven hydraulic pump.  Manual gear is simple.

I don't know the UK market too well, but just to give a world-relevant example, a Ford Focus might work.

One rule of thumb is the fewer things on the fan belt, the better. For instance my car does not have power steering, nor A/C, nor a smog air pump.

The complexity of the engine onboard computer is usually not a concern, since they are exceedingly reliable in most cars.  Sensors and actuators are the least reliable part, but they're cheap; the only real danger zone is doing poor diagnosis and concluding the computer is at fault when it's actually a sensor.  *In my experience computers rarely fail, but replacing the computer is an expensive way to reset the computer; so people see a notable improvement after doing so.  Always ask: "which sensor could cause this?"

Comment: I'm not sure you got the numbers right. OP has 12000 pound in savings. If they spend 3000 on a car they have quite a bit left for repairs and also make a surplus on their wage at the moment anyway. The original question was about a more expensive car, around 9000 pound and for that it kinda fits or if we assume OP directly spends the other savings on something else. A decent used car's repair cost will typically not exceed their price in a year (or even multiple ones) - especially if one restricts oneself to necessary repairs (i.e. perhaps not the air conditioning).

Comment: That being said, the DIY part obviously is a good option to save money on top - if one is up for it, otherwise one might also waste money in trying to fix something without success or in a way that creates even more damage... whether it fits for OP is obviously for them to decide.

Comment: @Frank the way I read it was, "75% of savings = £3000" (therefore savings=3000/0.75 or 4000).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers are focused on the fact that in your situation you absolutely shouldn't be spending so much on a car (and they're for sure correct). But I just wanted to answer what I suspect was your intention in the question: **"Should I pay in cash or pay in monthly installments"**

and the answer is that *it depends*. Where I'm from it's very common for car purchases (at dealers, many 2nd hand cars/dealers won't have this option) to offer a interest free period (of typically several years). I would recommend this as you get a fair amount of profit by just safely investing the money for that period while paying the minimum repayments. Once the interest free period ends, pay off the remainder in it's entirety. Just make sure that you are allowed to pay it off completely and for no extra cost. Also be sure to not use the money for anything else and end up not being able to make a repayment on time. If you feel you can't do this then you should just pay in cash upfront, you never want to be paying interest when you have the cash. (unless you can use the money for something that will make you money, such as an appreciating asset or an investment, (this also applies if the car is being used to make money))

Comment: "you never want to be paying interest when you have the cash".... I see what you mean. I decided when reading some answers (including yours) and comments to not go for installments. Obviously, I think I should find the best way to spend less and spend cash and keep building the savings for goods that have more value in long terms (ex : house, investments, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

**Do not buy a car. See update below.**

There are good answers already, let me add one that might seem tangential, but I feel is important, as it is very often ignored.

Do you **need** a car, or do you **want** a car?

- if the answer contains ideas like "I would get to the job quicker", "there is often bad weather", "I have to be presentable at my job", "I need to visit x/y/z few times a year", "I need to transport furniture to my new apartment", "It is much easier", "everybody else my age has it" etc. then it is a **want**, not a **need**, and you should consider alternatives (like using **bicycle or public transport** - do some research there, it is often quite more usable than people think).
- it the answer is more like "I'm starting a business which requires transporting hundreds of kg of stuff daily" or "I work night shifts and in my area there is >x% chance I'd get robbed/raped/killed" then it is probably a **need**. Still, moving to another location or changing business idea might change that need to "want".

Also note: You say you were saving for 15 months to save 4000 GBP. Note that once you get a car, it will take you **much longer** to save another 4000 GBP. And that you'd want another car in 10-20 years even if you buy new one. Many people don't realize until they do a detailed calculation that even if they were given a fuel for free, their car will cost them plenty (there is not only fuel cost, but also insurance, paying damages for incidents, possibility of damage and theft, yearly registration and technical checks, parking and other tickets, planed and unplanned maintenance and repairs, often overlooked and expensive [amortization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization) etc.)

**Update:**
After your update (and comment indicating you really only **want** it instead of **needing** it), I would ***advice against buying any car*** at this time (and especially against buying new one for 3000 GBP!)

It seems you can currently save about 160 GBP/month without owning car and living with parents.  I'd recommend to get a [bicycle](https://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2013/04/22/curing-your-clown-like-car-habit/) and/or use public transport. Get a taxi for those rare moments you miss a last public transport (and you didn't use bike).

You say you'd like to move to live on your own in few years - do a calculation - what is cost of rent in your area? How much are your parents covering (beside shelter) - food, clothing, hygiene, etc? Are those costs added **much less** than 160 GBP/month (and if so, how much less)? Even if they are only a fraction of that cost, You should still have a healthy stash before you decide to move out, as you will run into unexpected costs along the way.

Note that car (especially new one) is one of things that lose values very quickly - so you can't really go with *"I'll buy it and see how it goes, and sell it if it is not working financially"* - you'd easily lose 20-30% of the value the moment you buy it.

Car also has [many hidden costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics_of_car_use). Even after you buy it with cash, [car standing and running costs in USA can easily be 400 GBP/month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_costs)! Probably different in your area, but you should definitely invest some time to investigate local prices for all those components of car full cost, and calculate how much that car would REALLY cost you per month (Total cost of ownership)!

So - calculate cost of living alone, and calculate full cost of a car (not just a price of a car and gas!), and see if both of those combined are less than 160 GBP/month. If not, you will have to **give up** on one (or both) of your **wants** (either you will continue living with parents indefinitely, or you will not have a car) until you get a better paying job.

Comment: From what you said, I think I want a car. I but I would like to leave the office whenever I want at night as in public transportation, I may miss the last vehicle for instance. Sometimes, I just don't want to leave the office and do some personals stuff instead of wasting time in the INSANE traffic jam

Comment: @JasonKrs I've added an update to the answer. I do not think you should get a car as it is unlikely you can afford it - but please do calculations in your area using links I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to say as there are multiple factors you could look at.

The first is most people will assume paying cash is best since you won’t have to pay interest. Excellent point.

But if you get a very low-interest rate, you could probably finance the car and make more money by investing the cash instead of using it to pay for a car. That’s worth considering.

Here's my opinion:

A car is a depreciating asset which means its value is constantly dropping. So, paying cash for something that is losing money value means that you’re losing money in two directions which is not a good thing.

It only makes sense to start considering a car loan as an option when you have the cash available to pay for the car you want, but you feel like you can find a better use for that money that is worth paying the interest on the auto loan.

Evaluate the options in front of your basis and take an informed decision.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hello, your sentence about considering loan when cash is available is something I thought about... Very nice idea I think. Thank you sir